# Poker Main Pot is 100 and split in 3

Tags: rules

To make this scenario simple I just use small amount.

Scenario:

Main pot: $100

Player A: $30,

Player B: $30,

Player C: $30,

Player D: $10,

Player A, B, C, D checked. Then Player A raised $20 and Player B, C checked while Player D folded. Then on showdown, the 3 players tied.

The question is how should the pot split into 3? 
if by 33.333 there always be a missing of 00.001

Comment: You seem to use the terms "raised" and "checked" to mean "bet" and "called" here.

Comment: It's also not clear what the final pot size is: was it 100 before the action you describe, or after?

Answer (score 6):

Common casino rules are these: Pots are split as evenly as possible down to the smallest betting unit of the game. In a typical small game, that's usually a $1 chip, but in some games it might be a $5 chip or even bigger. The "odd" chip(s) left over after everyone gets the maximum equal amount are distributed differently depending on the game being played.

In games with blinds (like Texas Holdem and Draw games), extra chips are given to the players in order after the button. That is, eldest hand gets first odd chip, second eldest hand gets the next one, etc. In stud games, the odd chip(s) are given to the player with the highest single card in his hand (using the same high-card-by-suit ranking as for bring-ins), whether or not that card was played, then second-highest, etc.

In high-low split games, if the odd chip is caused by the initial split, it goes into the high pot, and then each pot is awarded as above. Some casinos have a special rule that if there is a single winner for high and multiple winners for low (a common occurrence in Omaha), the first odd chip goes into the low pot.

Answer (score 1):

The pot is split to the lowest chip you have in play, typically a one dollar chip. That gives each player 33 dollars with a one dollar remainder. Typically this dollar is given to the player in the earliest position.

Sometimes the odd chip is given to the last player.
Sometimes the odd chip is given to the dealer.
Sometimes the odd chip is left in the middle to be played for in the next hand.

You can really do it any way you want, the important thing is that you always do it the same way in your game in the interest of fairness.

Answer (score 0):

Split the pot as evenly as you can; then the remainder is distributed one minimum-value chip at a time starting with UTG and working round in order.

In your example, assuming $1 chips are the smallest and D has the button - A,B,C get $33 each, then A gets the final $1.